# Add arrow to table cell

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to be able to add an arrow to particular table cells in my table.  Each table cell has a border color, and i want the arrow to match.  Anyone know if this is possible.

Here is my basic table

[image]

And i would like to turn it into the following. Notice the arrow like border in the right side of the cell.  The vertical border has been removed.

Also if the column on the right is a different colour, i need to reflect this as well.  As this example image shows

[image]

Does anyone know if this is possible to do in CSS alone?  At the moment i build a normal table and set the background colors and border styles of each cell.

I don't really want to have to add an additional column for the arrows, but if this has to be done then i will do it, but not sure how I could color the borders of the arrow. I need to be able to cope with infinite colors as the user can choose these at runtime.

NOTE:  I do not know the size of the table cell, so would need something that would be dynamic, or use percentages.

**EDIT:**
If it makes it easier i am happy for the arrow to move to the left, like the first column in the new image below...

[image]

Comment: [This](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) may be of help to you

Comment: [I did this for divs](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/ZGCpq/), you may be able to change it for tds

Answer (score 3):

This may give you a start: http://jsfiddle.net/pxSs6/1/

I've created the arrows with `:before` pseudo-elements and the 'color-detection' is done via the adjacent sibling selector, like this:

```
.gray + td:before {
  border-left-color: gray;
}
```

I used `em` for the dimensions, but I guess you have to adapt the sizes to fit your needs.

Comment: Something along this line will work. There's a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35168) that's existed for years in Firefox that prevents any element being positioned realative to a `td`. You'd need to include a `div` in each cell, and then position your generated content realative to that.

Comment: This nearly works, and shows different colors if the columns are not the same color, but doesnt seem to show a border?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this page:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Could be exactly what you want with a good explanation

Comment: I have seen this, but my problem is, i am not sure how big the table cell is, because if could have 1 line of text or multiple lines, and this css requires a height and width value

Answer (score 0):

Is this any use to you? I'm not sure how adaptive it is, but it may give you a head start ;)

Apologise, my coding is probably terrible :/

CSS:

```
TABLE {
margin:0;
padding:0;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
text-align:left;
width:600px;
border:0 none;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
TH, TD {padding:4px; border-bottom:1px solid #fff; background-size:100%;}

tr:nth-child(odd) { background:#ddeff3; }
tr:nth-child(even) { background:#92cddc;}
TH {border: 1px solid #fff; background-color: #548dd4;}

.arrow {position: relative;}
.arrow:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right: -10px;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border: 11px solid transparent;
border-left: 12px solid #ddeff3;
z-index:2;
}
.arrow:before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right: -11px;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border: 11px solid transparent;
border-left: 12px solid #fff;
z-index:1;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) .arrow:after {border-left: 12px solid #ddeff3;}
tr:nth-child(odd) .arrow:before {border-left: 12px solid #fff;}
tr:nth-child(even) .arrow:after {border-left: 12px solid #92cddc;}
tr:nth-child(even) .arrow:before {border-left: 12px solid #fff;}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Template</th>
    <th scope="col">Measure</th>
    <th scope="col">Number</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="arrow">Subcontractor/Contract Feedback</td>
    <td class="arrow">Health and Safety</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="arrow">Subcontractor/Contract Feedback</td>
    <td class="arrow">Quality system</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="arrow">Subcontractor/Contract Feedback</td>
    <td class="arrow">Staff Performance</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The FIDDLE is here: http://jsfiddle.net/takuhii/6hbCv/1/

Comment: Thanks.. This is nearly perfect, but doesnt seem to work if columns are different colour?  Is it possible to make it work?